# How does grizzly parse http payload?

Tags: java, http, grizzly

Is there a grizzle parser to parse http payload as ByteArray and convert to HttpContent and HttpRequestPacket? 'I don't want to build own parser.

All http payloads are in a file and should be sent with grizzly framework to server.

Comment: Could you pls. a bit more explain what you are trying to achieve? What are you planning to do with the responses?

Comment: Ok. I get a http payload as byte[] from file and want to convert it to the object HttpRequestPacket for sending to server. I need a parser that parse http payload as byte[] and store in the HttpRequestPacket. The parser should be based on RFC 822 like the DefaultHttpRequestParser of apache httpcomponents. With HttpRequestPacket I can use better in grizzly framework e.g. connection pool etc. I want to use HttpFilter of grizzly to get HttpResponsePacket, so I should send HttpRequestPacket.

Comment: Convert also to HttpContent